# How to add 2 rows and 3 columns images?

Tags: html, css, image

My idea of this project is to put 2 rows and 3 columns to put images inside them. I'm using Laravel html Css(without Bootstrap).
What I want looks like this:[image]

Any idea how to start it?

Comment: use `CSS-Grid`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrap the images and apply `display: grid;` to the container.
2. To have 3 columns, use: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest and simplest way to achieve rows and columns is display: flex.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You could also use grid but grid is more complex and not used as often because it is harder to handle than flex. Flexbox is responsive, adjusts content to screen size so you can expand screen size to see how it works.

Code is very simple. CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpvjo26y/12/

Comment: Please read [answer]. Your answer effectivly is 
a [link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and as such does not fit the guidelines 
as an answer. PS: Also a fiddle as standalone is not allwoed according to the guidelines. Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) which also applies toe xternal fiddles and codepens. Use a [repro] instead.

Comment: Technically you are also wrong. Grid is not more complex or harder to handle then flex. It just have different purposes. Flexbox is good if you only need to control one dimension while grid can control both height and width at the same time. `grid` was rarely used because IE did not support it but since IE started to be deprecated at the 16th August 2021 it is no logner an issue. The one thing flexbox currently is better for is a masonry layout while `masonry-grid` is only supported by `moz`-browsers so far.

Comment: As I said I before I was making JS Fiddle example so not sure why you guide me on how to answer :)

Comment: It is a template answer for reviewing. And Like I said, a fiddle is insufficient you should use a [repro] instead.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of html structure this is what you need:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: images are not tabular data. As such you should not use a table in the first place (with exeption of e-mail templates). Beside of that, tables are a poor soltuion for responsivness.

Comment: there is no clarification in the question, so either your comment, this answer or using `display: table` and some `div`s as a table should be the answer

Comment: thanks for the placeholder and the comment @tacoshy. Never claimed that is a good solution. I only proposed that since he mentioned columns and rows. Probably flexbox is what he needs. Happy to remove it, if you think it's just noise.

Comment: it fullfils the criteria for an answer it is just bad practice for modern webdevelopment.